# Create a maven project with netbeans

Tags: java, image, maven, netbeans, tagging

I'm a beginner in maven as well as imagga annotation service. I'm trying to do [this tutorial](http://restunited.com/docs/5e5jucn55gzm#installation). I did the (Download and install) step. The second step is not described in details but I tried to do the best I can do. When I run the code in the test section I got this error

```
cd C:\Users\fatto\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject1; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_151" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.imagga.api.imagga.ImaggaTest\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_151\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom (8 KB at 6.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/mojo-parent/28/mojo-parent-28.pom

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/mojo-parent/28/mojo-parent-28.pom (26 KB at 40.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/codehaus-parent/3/codehaus-parent-3.pom

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/codehaus-parent/3/codehaus-parent-3.pom (5 KB at 8.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.jar

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.jar (37 KB at 37.9 KB/sec)

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building mavenproject1 0.1.0
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ mavenproject1 ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0/maven-plugin-api-2.0.pom

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0/maven-plugin-api-2.0.pom (601 B at 1.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.1/commons-exec-1.1.pom

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.1/commons-exec-1.1.pom (11 KB at 25.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.1/commons-exec-1.1.jar

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.1/commons-exec-1.1.jar (52 KB at 90.3 KB/sec)
Calling endpoint: categorize
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ApiInvoker
  location: class com.imagga.api.imagga.ImaggaTest
    at com.imagga.api.imagga.ImaggaTest.testCategorizeCategorizations(ImaggaTest.java:17)
    at com.imagga.api.imagga.ImaggaTest.main(ImaggaTest.java:142)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.944s
Finished at: Thu Jan 11 01:37:51 AST 2018
Final Memory: 6M/123M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project mavenproject1: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I'm not sure did I create the project on a wrong way or what is the exact problem.

The code after copying it and paste it in the project looks like the following image

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRaHb.png)

I'm not sure about the reason of the redlines

The project after the build using commandline

[Build result with command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR3yM.png)

Thank you

Comment: There is a syntax error in file `ImaggaTest.java` on line 17, did you take a look at it?

Comment: I'm copying the exact code from that tutorial from the testing section?! @hoefling

Comment: I updated the question with the screenshot, I have some red lines on the methods and the imports.@hoefling

Comment: Does the project build without error? Could you try to build it using maven from the command line ?

Comment: @gdegani I updated the question with the build result

Comment: Have you already tried to execute the test from the command line as described at the end of the file? // Run this file:
//   cd Imagga-java
//   mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.imagga.api.imagga.ImaggaTest"

Comment: @gdegani I updated the question with the result I got

Comment: 1) post your pom.xml, 2) post all the output and run maven with -e. I downloaded the same example and it works:https://gist.github.com/gdegani/786f19fa40e40f4c560165f2698ca1e9

Comment: @gdegani I commented on your post to make sure that I'm doing the steps on the right way.